# form action in flask not redirecting to the route

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-login

Simply I am just trying to redirect to an url by using the below code in my login.html template:

```
     <form>
          <form action="/sessions">      
          <p>Username:</p>
          <p><input type="text" minlength="8" name="username"required /></p>
          <p>Password:</p>
          <p><input type="text" name="password"/></p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and

```
def login():
    print("inside login")
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route("/sessions", methods=["GET","POST"])
def sessions():
    userid  = request.form.get("userid")
    password  = request.form.get("password")
    return request.form.get("userid"), request.form.get("password")
```

but is stuck on the login() url. Also I tried

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('sessions') }}">
```

but is not working as well. Not sure what I am missing? Please any hints/ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: Where do you want the page to be redirected? I mean what html do you want the /sessions route to serve?

Comment: I want to /sessions to be routed to session.html but using the  <form action="/sessions">

Comment: @user6702954 Glad to help. If you have resolved your issue and one of the answers helped, mark as a accepted answer for others to see what helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated answer reflects new comments

Found couple issues in your code:

1. `HTML` form is incorrect, you are using form in form

```html
     <form>
          <form action="/sessions">      
          <p>Username:</p>
          <p><input type="text" minlength="8" name="username"required /></p>
          <p>Password:</p>
          <p><input type="text" name="password"/></p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

You should change it to this

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is login page</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="POST">
            <p>Username:</p>
            <p><input type="text" minlength="8" name="username"required /></p>
            <p>Password:</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="password"/></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice changes, first there is only 1 `form` tag, then I use `jinja2` engine to call the `login` in `form.action`, 2nd this `login` page handles serving `login` `HTML` when there is a `GET` request (initially opening this page) and for accepting form `POST` request with credentials.

Then I changed the routes to this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_name = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(user_name, password)  # do something here?
        return redirect(url_for('session'))
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/session')
def session():
    return render_template('session.html')
```

Notice that now `login` accepts both methods, `GET` and `POST`, as mentioned before, `GET` is for serving `HTML` content and `POST` is for submitting `form` data. In the `login` endpoint I have a condition that checks, if it's a `POST` method request, then I extract credential details from `request.form` and after doing something (e.g. in that print() statement`I`return redirect(url_for('session'))`.

This is how you manage redirects from one page to another by clicking submit on one of a pages.

## original answer that was incorrect

In Flask to redirect, you could you something like this:

```py
from flask import url_for, redirect

@app.route('/sessions', methods['GET', 'POST']
def sessions():
    # some code
    return redirect(url_for('some.endpoint'))
```

This will redirect you to a specific endpoint that you will provide. In the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) there is more info about it.

Comment: I wanted to redirect using the <form action="/sessions">      at the template

Comment: What do you meam by saying "using form"? Do you want to be redirected after clicking a button in the provided form?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want. After clicking the submit button in the form I want to redirect to '/sessions'

Comment: P.s. you will not be redirected to `/sessions` if you use it like this: `<form action="/sessions">`, this will basically send a `form` data to `/sessions` and will return what ever you want, first change to this `<form action="/sessions" method='post'>` and then you can do something like this:  `/sessions` return like this `return redirect(url_for('session')) if request.method == 'POST' else return render_template('session.html')`

Comment: great thanks a lot for your help. Now is working like a charm. your explanation wonderfull btw:). The thing is I did watched one of those videos from Harvard IT school and the lecturer made it look like so simple. thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ( i just added one more line, the commented one):

```
@app.route("/sessions", methods=["GET","POST"])
def sessions():
    userid  = request.form.get("userid")
    password  = request.form.get("password")
    if request.method == 'POST':  #additional line
        return request.form.get("userid"), request.form.get("password")
```