# POST method with flask doesn't work. (HTML form)

Tags: python, http, flask, request

What happens is when I select the file and click on upload, it just reloads the page passing the parameter: `?file=` in the "/" route, the `/upload` route isn't called with the post method, it just goes back to "/" with `?file="file` which I chose" instead of `/upload`. The file is not sent because the upload function wasn't called and the upload route wasn't used.

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:\Users\caiop\Downloads\test'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET']) #being ignored..........
    def upload():
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Check if the POST request has a file part
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                return "test001"
            
            file = request.files['file']
            
            # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an empty part without filename
            if file.filename == '':
                return "test000"
            # If the file exists and is valid, save it to a designated folder (e.g., 'uploads')
            
            if file:
                #try:
                file_path = UPLOAD_FOLDER
                file.save(file_path + file.filename)
                    
                return "OK"
                                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```html
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="inner-form" id="upload">
  <input id="filer" type="file" name="file">
  <input id="typer" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

This should return 127.0.0.1/upload showing just "OK" on the screen and the file uploaded to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem through this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262301/form-action-in-flask-not-redirecting-to-the-route) "**form is incorrect, you are using form in form**" , basically the form to send the file was inside another form and that made my form with the upload action not work., I didn't post my complete html because I didn't think it was necessary but it was close to this:

```
        <form>
            <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="inner-form" id="upload">
               <input id="filer" type="file" name="file">
              <input id="typer" type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

wrong way   ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, and I managed to get it working by making a slight change to the `file_path` as shown below:

```py
if file:
    try:
        file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename)
        file.save(file_path)
        return "OK"
    except Exception as e:
        return "An error occurred while saving the file: " + str(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I missed this detail that was also having a problem: os.path.join.